# Neo4j ETL components DB-support

Tags: neo4j

On Graph connect 2017 in London I listened Praveena Fernandes when she spook about NEO4J ETL Components toolbox in terms of migrate relation databases to a GraphDatabase.

During the speech she mentioned that the tool supported, among others, DB2 and Oracel relationdatabases.

When I download the etl I can only find support for MySQL and PostgreSQL

Does anyone know the ETL support DB2 and Oracel databases

Regards 
//Andreas

Answer (score 0):

We just added Oracle support some days ago.
If you have a look at the [git repo](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-etl-components), you'll see it.

I also documented a bit how to run ETL with Oracle, [here](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-etl-components/#_example_session_docker_northwind).

A new release is on the way. Just running some more tests...

Feel free to reach us for further help.